# How to pass script parameters containing spaces or quotes to PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I can run (for the command line)

```
myscript.py '--pm execute.shell(cmd="ls -l", nonInteractive=True)'
```

But, suppose I was to debug myscript.py with and set the "Script parameters:" field in the Edit Configurations Python dialog to:

```
--pm execute.shell(cmd="ls -l", nonInteractive=True)
```

it barfs at space between "ls" and "-l". Is there a way to workaround this? Using ' or " quotes seems not to do it:

```
--pm 'execute.shell(cmd="ls -l", nonInteractive=True)'
--pm "execute.shell(cmd='ls -l', nonInteractive=True)"
```

In both cases, the quotes end up in the arguments.

---

Update:
Running:

```
import sys
for x in sys.argv:
    print "<%s>"%(x,)
```

with

```
Script parameters: a  \ b " c" "\ d" ' e' '\ f' "a 'b' \"c\""
```

gives:

```
<cmd.py>
<a>
<\>
<b>
< c>
<\ d>
<'>
<e'>
<'\>
<f'>
<a 'b' "c">
```

So it looks like:

- escaping is ignored (\ is treated literally), except for preceding "
- a non-escaped " starts a block that may contain spaces
- ' is treated literally

So, the magic answer is:

```
Script parameters:  --pm "execute.shell(cmd='ls -l', nonInteractive=True)"
```

or

```
Script parameters:  --pm "execute.shell(cmd=\"ls -l\", nonInteractive=True)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about the issue. Since I don't have commenting privileges, I am writing it as answer.

Changing "ls -l" to "ls-\ l" should work, at least on *nix systems.

The relevant documentation/bug report is at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-4715 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72632 which states that you need to escape spaces using system dependent methods, and not using a generic method. The proposal for a generic system independent method was apparently denied.

EDIT: --pm" "execute.shell(cmd=\"ls" "-l\"," "nonInteractive=True) worked.

Comment: Sadly, "a\ b" gets interpreted as ["a\", "b"]  (which is the standard escaping on my *nix ubuntu VM)

Comment: --pm" "execute.shell(cmd=\"ls" "-l\"," "nonInteractive=True) should work. Can you try this before I edit the answer?

Comment: According to pycharm docs, it seems space have to be input as inside quotes, and quotes as \. It seems quite odd choice. Url is https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html

Comment: @AkshatHarit Thank you for the link which saved me hours of searching.